# Is this sample size calculation I found in the meta-analysis by Martensson et al. (2015) correct?

Tags: statistical-power, meta-analysis

I am basing my sample size calculation for a study I am planning on a meta-analysis by Martensson et al. (2015). There is a sentence in this meta-analysis that is making me doubt my sample size calculation. It's this sentence: "Twenty participants per treatment arm imply approximately 80% power to detect an effect size of 0.5 standard deviations". When I enter 20 participants, d = 0.5 and alpha = 0.05 into GPower, I get a power of 34% for a two-tailed independent samples t-test, 46% if I make it one-tailed, and for a one-tailed matched pairs t-test 69.5%. However, this is still not really approximately 80% and the studies in the meta-analysis (which is on light therapy against winter depression) usually have independent samples, so I don't think this is what they meant. Did I make a mistake or did they?

B. Mårtensson, A. Pettersson, L. Berglund, L. Ekselius, Bright white light therapy in depression: A critical review of the evidence. J. Affect. Disord. 182, 1–7 (2015). doi: 10.1016/j.jad.2015.04.013

Comment: ```The effect size was defined as the standardized mean difference (SMD), which was calculated as the difference of the mean outcome measure (SIGH-SAD(-SR)/HDRS scores) between the bright white light therapy group and the placebo group, divided by the pooled standard deviation. ``` their definition is a little bit different than the traditional definition. Moreover, I think the authors wrote that statement in regards to ANOVA analysis. 2 group n=20 sample with effect size 0.5 and significance of 0.05 results in 86% power

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, V. Aslanyan! But isn't that the common definition of Cohen's d and the one used by GPower? https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_d

Comment: you are correct. The second statement about power analysis does not change though

Comment: I see, I get 86% power if I do the power calculation using an effect size f = 0.5. I think that might be what they did, thanks a lot for this idea! In that case, I think they shouldn't say “an effect size of 0.5 standard deviations”. D says how big the effect is in terms of standard deviations, f would need to be multiplied by 2 to say how big the effect is in terms of standard deviations.